# If every linear operator on a normed space bounded, is it possible to infer that the space is finite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

It is well known that every linear operator on a finite dimensional normed space is bounded (continuous).

The question that presents itself: is the reverse also true ?

I mean: let $X$ be a normed space (we don't whether it is finite or infinite dimensional). In addition, every linear operator on $X$ is bounded (continuous). Is it possible to infer that the space $X$ is finite dimensional ?

Comment: Please write an *informative* title so that others can find this problem and solution later.